# Dimensionality of a Lie algebra and relation to particle physics

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra

This question of mine is coming from a course that I took in Mathematical Physics where the professor was taking about lie algebras and lie groups. I did not quite understand some things and I don't seem to be able to reach her so I thought I better post my questions here, for a wider audience to respond to. I have two rather elementary questions. Bear with me, here it goes.

When we talk about the mathematical structure of an Algebra, we associate with it a vector space and a bilinear operation (lie bracket) in addition to some other properties we would like it to obey (Jacobi identity, anti-commutation, bi-linearity). When we talk about Lie Algebras of let's say SO(3), the vector space we refer to is the space of the generators $J_{x}$, $J_{y}$, $J_{z}$ with commutator as the lie bracket. We can represent J's uniquely as 3x3 matrices up to a similarity transformation.

Now, we make a similarity transformation on the $J_{x}$, $J_{y}$, and $J_{z}$ to diagonalize $J_{z}$ and work in this basis of $J_{+}$, $J_{-}$, and $J_{z}$. We identify the eigenstates of $J_{z}$ as $|m\rangle$ and the corresponding eigenvalue as $m$. We act on $|m\rangle$ by $J_{+}$ and realize that it gives us some $c_{m+1}|m+1>$. We can continuously keep doing this and climbing up this ladder infinitely. But there's a problem because that would mean that $J_{z}$ has infinite eigenfunctions with infinite eigenvalues which is not the case. Thus, we conclude that this ladder must terminate somewhere and we call this maximum state as |j$\rangle$ with a corresponding eigenvalue j (when acted on by $J_{z}$).

Working out the constants like $c$ through the commutation relations we realize that given a $j$, we have $2j+1$ eigenstates of $J_{z}$. For example, $j=1/2$ implies, $m=1/2, -1/2$. Now coming to my question.

The professor claimed that increasing the js just means that we get higher-dimensional representations of the lie algebra. For a given $j$, we have $2j+1$ dimensional representation of the lie algebra. This, I do not understand. Because the dimension of a lie algebra refers to the dimension of the vector space it underlies; in this case, the vector space spanned by $J_{+}$, $J_{-}$, and $J_{z}$. Since there are 3 basis vectors in this vector space ($J_{+}$, $J_{-}$, and $J_{z}$), shouldn't the dimension of this lie algebra be fixed to 3? And in that case, what does a higher dimensional representation even mean for an algebra? I understand higher dimensional representations of a group that come from tensors but I cannot seem to resolve this idea of dimensionality of a lie algebra that comes from the underlying vector space which is fixed in dimension.

Coming to my second question. Historically, how was the relationship between group theory and particle physics established?  For instance, was it that we had the angular momentum algebra with all the cumbersome spherical harmonics, and Legendre polynomials, and then somebody made the connection between the Lie algebra of $SU(2)$? And what was the first connection made between a particle and irreducible representation of the group it entails? I am just having trouble understanding how all of this ties up.

I hope someone shall answer my questions satisfactorily or direct me to possible duplicates (I did some searching and did not find anything convincing on stack exchange). I believe that there is something simple that I do not see.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear as to what you're asking? I feel like your question got lost in the details

Comment: To reopen this post (v2), consider to only ask 1 question per post, keeping in mind not to invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

> And in that case, what does a higher dimensional representation even mean for an algebra?

The lie algebra dimension is indeed 3, but it can be represented in n-dimensional vector space. The representation of some element of lie algebra in 1D space would be a number, in 2D space a 2x2 matrix, in 3D space 3x3 matrix and so on. So by increasing j you are increasing the dimension of the matrix that represents the algebra element.

The n-dimensional representation of algebra is simply representation of algebra for n-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Ah, neat. Thanks for the clarification!